# Why is Android Compose kind of merging the widgets inside a Column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For context: I'm following the official [Jetpack Compose Basics Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-basics#4) and I've encountered a weird behavior in the preview of the UI.

This is the Activity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.basicscodelab.ui.theme.BasicsCodelabTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BasicsCodelabTheme {
                MyApp()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the preview composable:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    BasicsCodelabTheme {
        MyApp()
    }
}
```

This is the Greeting composable:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
    ) {
        Row {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(24.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello,")
                Text(text = "$name!")
            }
            OutlinedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Show more")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now, the piece of code I'm having problems with:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(names: List<String> = listOf("World, Compose")) {
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp)) {
            Greeting(name = "World")
            Greeting(name = "Compose")
        }
    }
}
```

Following the video, this is the expected result (more or less, I still have to figure out why the OutlinedButton is just the outline of a button):
[image]

But I'm supposed to make use of the `names` parameter. So, I first tried this:

```
names.forEach { name -> Greeting(name) }
```

But the result is some weird fusion of the Greeting components:
[image]

It also happens if I try to do the loop like this:

```
for (name in names) {
    Greeting(name)
}
```

The weirdest of it all is that the word "Compose" isn't even trying to occupy the same space as the word "World", which is what I could expect (if they weren't inside of a Column, but they are). It's some weird fusion as if Compose was thinking "OK, I see what you're trying to do: here", but it got it all wrong.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line `fun MyApp(names: List<String> = listOf("World, Compose")) {`

Here the List contains only one string "World, Compose".

Change it to `listOf("World", "Compose")`. It will work.

Comment: Dammit, I don't know how long I spent looking at the code, and I managed to miss that... Thanks!